# Writing to nextline in Excel 2007

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel-2007

Currently, I have the following method that writes to excel 2007.

```
public static void createSpreadsheet(String msg)
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        Excel.Range oRng;
        oXL = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.get_Item(1);
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        oXL.Visible = true;
        oXL.UserControl = false;
        oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "A" + 1);
        oRng.Value2 = msg;

    }
```

However, whatever msg I sent, it only get to write to column A1 which is evident from the code above.

How do I expand the code above so that whenever additional messages are sent, they are appended below the previously written column.?? 
In a console app, I could do this: Console.writeline(msg). How do I achieve that in excel?

Eg: Msg 1 (Col A1) 
    Msg 2 (Col A2)
    Msg 3 (Col A3)
    ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable called `currentColumn` and pass it to the method:

```
public static void createSpreadsheet(String msg, column)
```

In calling:

```
// there is an integer variable called currentColumn
createSpreadsheet("a message", currentColumn++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the A1 cell currently.  If you want to write to some other row, just change the parameters to your range.  For example:

```
oRng = oSheet.Range["A" + rowNumber, "A" + rowNumber];
oRng.Value = msg;
```

And now you can dynamically increment rowNumber after each message.  Same thing works for columns, just replace "A" with the appropriate column.